# Asking politely for a meeting

Tags: politeness

I would like to politely ask my professor to meet me sometime soon. Could someone please let me know (1) whether my sentences are grammatically correct and also not weird to the ears of a native English speaker and (2) whether they sound polite. Any other suggestion would be appreciated.

1 - I would be grateful if we could meet at your earliest convenience.

2 - I would be grateful if you could arrange/set up a meeting at your earliest convenience.

3 - I don't suppose you could arrange a meeting, could you?

Comment: #1 is the best choice. #2, is basically the same, but redundant. #3 is not appropriate.

Comment: 'At your earliest convenience' conveys a sense of urgency. I would remove that and replace it with a more direct question, e.g. I would be grateful if we could meet. Would you have some time/ be available later this week?

Comment: @GrandTorini "I'd be grateful if we could meet some time" also works, right?

Comment: @F.K that's extremely vague, you might want to specify what timeframe you have in mind. Eg: 'I'd be grateful if we could meet sometime this week/ this month/ prior to the exam. Would you be available?'

Comment: @GrandTorini I actually want to imply that I'm very flexible about the timing, and I'm okay with whenever works best for him. How could I put that?

Comment: @F.K just say so, eg 'I am flexible and I can adapt to your schedule. If could suggest a date and time that would suit you, even later in the day/week/month/year, that would be much appreciated'

Comment: @F.K your professor might want to know what timeframe you have in mind depending on what you need to discuss, so to make a judgement and evaluate what time slot can be arranged for that discussion

Comment: @GrandTorini Thank you very much. Is "sometime that works best for you" weird? I could not find any similar sentences to it. I'm planning to write "sometime next week" but I'm just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @F.K yes, in a professional/ academic context it sounds a bit weird. Your professor won't schedule a meeting at a time that doesn't work for him. A similar sentence that is somewhat more formal would be 'at any time that suits you'

Comment: @GrandTorini Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all grammatically correct. However, in terms of politeness, I think the first works best. The other 2 have a much different tone because of how central the pronoun 'you' is in their constructions. By using that the tone of the sentence comes off much more as a demand than a question.